# ¿Hay alguna manera de evitar que la biblioteca Lity se active al arrastrar una imagen que utiliza Lity?

Tags: javascript, php, html, slider, lity

Tengo un slider de imágenes que es arrastrable. Estas imágenes tienen implementada la biblioteca `Lity`, la cual se utiliza para abrir un lightbox cuando el usuario hace clic en cada imagen.

El problema es que no puedo arrastrar las imágenes para navegar por el slider porque `Lity` se activa cada vez que suelto el clic después de arrastrar las imágenes.

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de evitar eso. Necesito que `Lity` se active solo cuando hago clic en la imagen, pero no cuando la arrastro.

Esta es la [biblioteca JavaScript Lity](https://github.com/jsor/lity) a la que me refiero.

También dejé [este issue en Github](https://github.com/jsor/lity/issues/290) para ver si alguien puede ayudarme allí.

¡Gracias!

Este es el código que tengo. Pero aquí no hay nada muy relevante. Solo un `foreach` para imprimir las imágenes y el atributo `data-lity` en cada una, que es lo que activa el lightbox.

```
<div class="small-slider__slider">
<?php
foreach ( $args['screenshots'] as $screenshot ) : ?>
    <article class="small-slider__item">
        <div class="post__image">
            <?php if ( ! empty( $src_low_res ) || ! empty( $src_high_res ) ) : ?>
                <a data-lity href="<?php echo esc_url( $src_high_res ); ?>">
                    <img loading="lazy" src="<?php echo esc_url( $src_low_res ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( $alt ); ?>">
                </a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </article>
    <?php
endforeach;
?>
</div>
```

Nota: la biblioteca de JavaScript Lity funciona bien, excepto por el problema descrito, y la biblioteca de JavaScript del slider (que se llama [Flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/)) también me funciona bien, la funcionalidad de arrastrar funciona perfectamente. Y no tengo errores en la consola.

Si algo no está claro, por favor déjame un comentario con tu pregunta.

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de darle mil vueltas y probar muchas cosas, llegué a la única solución que me funcionó. (Puse la pregunta ayer pero en realidad llevo más tiempo dándole vueltas)

- Del HTML original solo quité el `<a>` y el atributo `data-lity` para que no se lance por defecto. Dejé solo la imagen.
- A la imagen le agregué un nuevo atributo `data-high-res` para almacenar ahí la URL que se abrirá cuando el lightbox de Lity se lance.

  ```
    <div class="small-slider__slider">
    <?php foreach ( $args['screenshots'] as $screenshot ) :
    $src_low_res  = esc_url( $screenshot['src_low_res'] );
    $src_high_res = esc_url( $screenshot['src_high_res'] );
    $alt          = ! empty( $screenshot['alt'] ) ? esc_attr( 
    $screenshot['alt'] ) : 'Screenshot of plugin: ' . esc_attr( 
    $args['post_title'] ); ?>
    <article class="small-slider__item">
        <div class="post__image">
            <?php if ( ! empty( $src_low_res ) || ! empty( $src_high_res ) ) : ?>
                <img data-high-res="<?php echo esc_url( $src_high_res ); ?>" loading="lazy" src="<?php echo esc_url( $src_low_res ); ?>" alt=" 
                <?php echo esc_attr( $alt ); ?>">
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </article>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
  ```

Como no puedo utilizar el evento `click` típico, porque este se va a lanzar también cuando arrastro, lo hice con la ayuda de los eventos de la librería que uso para crear el slider.

Esta librería se llama [Flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/events), y me di cuenta que tiene un evento propio llamado `staticClick` que reacciona a un click estático, es decir sin movimiento. Según la documentación oficial:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, yo tenía el slider inicializado de esta manera:

```
   smallSliderElem.forEach(element => {
      const flick = new Flickity(element, smallSliderOptions);
   });
```

- Y lo que hice fue anclarme al evento `staticClick` y lanzar el Lity manualmente en ese momento, quedando así el javascript:

  ```
  smallSliderElem.forEach(element => {
  const flick = new Flickity(element, smallSliderOptions);

  flick.on( 'staticClick', function( event, pointer, cellElement, cellIndex ) {
    if('undefined' === typeof event.target.dataset.highRes) {
      return;
    }
    Lity(event.target.dataset.highRes);
  });

    });
  ```

Como todo está en un `foreach` que puede crear muchos sliders, con el `if` garantizo que solo se lance el Lity en los sliders que tengan el atributo `data-high-res`.

Espero que esto ayude a las personas que usan el Lity y Flickity a la vez y se hayan encontrado con el mismo problema.